# Another way to display an XPS document using WPF

Tags: wpf, xps, documentviewer, xpsviewer

I would like to ask if there are any other alternatives, aside from DocumentViewer, for displaying an XPS document in a WPF application? A ready-to-use control or class in .NET if possible.

This is because DocumentViewer is a little slow when you are scrolling through the pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, unless there are any third-party controls that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NiXPS](http://www.nixps.com/) to convert your XPS document to PDF and use any PDF viewer for WPF out there. This way you will get better performance than you do with DocumentViewer.